# Is this a safe way to shuffle Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

Unlike python javascript does not have `Array.prototype.shuffle()`method. 
So I implemented like below:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.sort((a, b)=> Math.random() * 2 - 1); //simple shuffle
console.log(arr);
```

I don't know whether this code is safe enough to use.

Comment: No, it is not. Use a Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Thanks, I found Fisher-Yates shuffle is common and works well.